# Texas Hold'em Questions RE: Use of cards on the table.

Tags: hand

Lost a hand last night that i did not agree with. Came was 7 Hold'em. The table had two Q's and 10's. Two pair. I had a pair of 4's and my opponent had a Q and a 9. He said he won because the two pair on the table was the best hand and his Q was the 5th card. The highest card i had was a 4. My position was that the two pair won since it was he and I and the two pair canceled that out. Who won the hand?

Comment: @HerbWolfe You almost have privilege to close.  I up vote most of your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the board was QQTTx and your opponent had Qx against your 44, then he wins with a full house, Queens full of Tens.

Question is somewhat unclear though and would benefit from some clarification to be more precise, plus will likely be flagged and closed as a duplicate.